# Are there rules for weapons dealing more or less damage against bigger or littler monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage

For example, in *AD&D 2E* a longsword deals 1d8 points of damage to medium and littler creatures and 1d12 points of damage to large or bigger creature. Does *5E* have any rules for weapons dealing different amounts of damage based on the size of the monster that's being attacked?

Comment: Do you own the 5e player's handbook? Have you read the PHB? Is there anything that makes you think that damage *does* increase against large and larger monsters?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. One of the ways to earn reputation is by posing a question that appears well researched. Without some background, this questions appears to be referencing a previous edition without investigating the edition in question. Including as part of the question, for example, that you're unfamiliar with *5E*, that *that* was your favorite old-timey rules quirk, that you wonder how such house rules would affect game balance, or *whatever* reason caused you to ask might go a long way toward getting a more positive result from the question. Thanks for participating.

Comment: Downvoters please consider [What do we do with "read the book to me" questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5270/23970) before just piling on.... If you've something to add to doppelgreener's description/analysis of a "case 2 RTBTM" please weigh in.

Comment: The weapons table in the [basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf)is the same as in the PHB.  If you don't have the PHB, at least you can use that as a reference for the basic game engine before asking the question.  Is this question looking for published material outside of the MM, DMG, and PHB?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast (The question's seeming pursuit of non-core rules might be the product of this editor's meddling. Check the edit history for details.)

Answer (score 5):

### No.

There's not really much else to say. To some extent the simulationism of larger/smaller creatures being easier or harder to hit is baked into their dexterity, AC, or features. (Mostly dexterity, from a casual skim of the MM.)